# Infinit Loop when socket client disconnect

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, null, serversocket

I had implemented a Java Multithreading Socket Server. It's working fine and create a new thread for every new client connection. But I have a bug when the TCP connection is cutted by the client, the server enter in a infinit loop and i got this message for  every loop:

```
ERROR : Bad Frame  !!! : null
```

I tried to debug the execution and change the `if else` condition but always the same bug exist when a client disconnect.

Here is my server Code

```
public class TCPSockServer implements Runnable {

    Socket sock;
    static int counter = 0;
    private static int TIMEOUT = 50000;
    private static int MAX_TIMEOUT = 100000;
    long lastReadTime;


    public TCPSockServer(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(12000);

            System.out.println("TCPSockServer : Listening to PORT 12000 ...");

            while (true) {
                Socket newSock = serverSock.accept();
                counter++;
                InetAddress addr = newSock.getInetAddress();
                System.out.println("TCPSockServer : Connection Number : "+ counter);
                System.out.println("TCPSockServer : Connection made to "
                        + addr.getHostName() + " : (" + addr.getHostAddress()
                        + ")");
                newSock.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                newSock.setKeepAlive(true);
                new Thread(new TCPSockServer(newSock)).start();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Trackiz: Main : ERROR Connection Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int clientID = counter;
        try {

            BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    sock.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder inString = new StringBuilder();
            String frame = null;
            PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                if (inString.append((String) inStream.readLine()) == null) {
                    System.out.println("TCPSockServer : CLIENT NOT CONNECTED");
                    sock.close();
                    break;
                } else {
                    lastReadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    frame = inString.toString();

                    if (cond1(frame)) {
                        ......
                    }else{
                     system.err.println("\nERROR : Bad Frame  !!! : "+frame); // why it enter this else in an infinit loop
                    }
                    outStream.println(provt.sendCommand("TCPSockServer : ACK TO CLIENT"));
                    inString = null;
                    inString = new StringBuilder();

                }
            }
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            sock.close();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            if (!isConnectionAlive()) {
                System.out.println("\nCONNECTION TERMINATED FROM CLIENT !"
                        + clientID);
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "TCPSockServer : Connection terminated with Client");
                try {
                    sock.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // TODO sendHeartBeat(); 
                System.out.println("Sending HeartBeat ...");
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("TCPSockServer : Connection Timeout. Try to reconnect !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

    public boolean isConnectionAlive() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastReadTime < MAX_TIMEOUT;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `append` method will never return `null`, so this is not right, the `if`-branch will never be entered:

```
  if (inString.append((String) inStream.readLine()) == null) {
```

The code should probably look more like this:

```
  String line = inStream.readLine();
  if (line == null) {
      ...
  } else {
      inString.append(line);
      ...
  }
```

Comment: I don't mean that if else. I speek about this one :  if (cond1(frame)) {
                        ......
                    }else{
                     system.err.println("\nERROR : Bad Frame  !!! : "+frame);
                    } /// I don't know why it enter the else and print 'Error bad frame = null ' in an infinit loop

Comment: The problem is that when the connection is closed the execution enters the else branch with your if-statement. The error is in the code before the if (cond1)-statement.